# Where can I find the implementation for IVCWizCtlUI

Tags: c#

**Background:**

I have an visual studio C++ custom project template to create a custom solution. When we say new project and select this custom template, it would ask for an xml file and create a visual c++ solution, substituting values from the xml file to the template files.

**What am trying to do now?**

I wanted to automate this process, (no user intervention to open visual studio and select the custom template). Infact to use the component in C#. This component has a dependency with visual studio wizard as shown in sample javascript

**Difficulties faced?**

The xml parser is a com component, which takes visual studio wizard as a parameter. Only if i set this properly, i can proceed further. The wizard is basically implements the below interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vswizard.ivcwizctlui_members(v=VS.90).aspx

Not sure how to access this wizard in C#.

**Current Javascript code:**

```
var aConverter = new ActiveXObject("NAMESPACE.MYParser");

//Problem: Not sure how to set this value, when "NAMESPACE.MYParser" used in C#
aConverter.Wizard = window.external;

aConverter.Filename = xmlfile;

//This method if called from C# without setting "aConverter.Wizard" throws exception
aConverter.ParseMyXML();

var value = aConverter.Someproperty;
```

**Prior research:**

I tried to use dte.LaunchWizard, but still i get an UI popped up, which i need to avoid. LaunchWizard not a good way for me, as i wanted direct control in C# for "NAMESPACE.MYParser"

Comment: Great first post.  Just a tip though, to get your code to show up nicely, indent everything with 4 spaces.  Alternatively, you should be able to just select the code and hit the keyboard combination: `Ctrl+K`.  And as a last tip, it isn't necessary to include the final `Thanks` or your name at the end, the thanks is unnecessary and your name already appears on the page.  Otherwise, great start.  :)

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your feedback. I have updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It may be not exactly the same direction as you want to go, but have you considered using **CMake**(open source) for that?

CMake is a tool for automatically setting up code-projects/toolsets on different plattforms and IDEs. CMake can also generate VisualStudio solutions, so all you would have to do is set up your CMake config files, and just generate the solution. You can also incorporate parameters, so that the user is able to costumize the project to be generated even further.

It is a great tool, runs on most platforms and there is also an easy to use GUI available. Check it out: http://www.cmake.org/